# Getting error as Failed to create data storage when trying to load the data from HDFS with MovieLens data

Tags: hadoop, ant, apache-pig, bigdata

I am trying to load data from HDFS to Pig but I am getting error as Failed to create Data Storage.
The command that I executed was:

```
movies = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/Movie_Lens/ratings' USING PigStorage(':') AS (user_id, dummy1, movie_id, dummy2, movie_rating, dummy3, timestamp);
```

I tried to find the mentioned problem in stack overflow but the link that I got are not related to HDFS and Pig, they are related to HDFS and HBase or Pig and HBase.

The detail of the log file is mentioned below.

Somewhere in the log file I found this mentioned:
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

### Pig Stack Trace

ERROR 1200: Failed to create DataStorage

```
Failed to parse: Failed to create DataStorage
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:201)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1707)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1680)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:623)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:505)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create DataStorage
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.init(HDataStorage.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.<init>(HDataStorage.java:53)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonMetadata.findMetaFile(JsonMetadata.java:109)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonMetadata.getSchema(JsonMetadata.java:189)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage.getSchema(PigStorage.java:538)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:89)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:901)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3568)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1625)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.init(HDataStorage.java:70)
    ... 23 more
```

To solve this problem I tried doing 'ant'
so when I run the command

```
bash ant -version
```

in ant bin folder it is working
but when I am running the command

```
bash ant clean jar-all -Dhadoopversion=23
```

in bin folder it is not working. In some of the links I found that new version of pig does not have jar-all command so I tried the following command

```
bash ant clean jar -Dhadoopversion=23
```

and this command is also not working.

Comment: I hope you checked this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/FAQ#FAQ-Q:WhatshallIdoifIsaw"FailedtocreateDataStorage"?

Comment: Yeah, before posting my question I had referred to this link and followed its step but it was not working.

Comment: I restarted my system and now loading data from hdfs into pig is working fine. Dont know how this magic happened.